# What are the dangers of starting a thread in the Application Start in global.asax? (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

If you start a thread in the Application Start of an asp.net site, what will happen when Application Stop is triggered? Also, the thread I'm starting will run forever.

For instance if there are no active sessions for a while, the application is stopped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/67557.aspx) to Rick Strahl’s blog. He shows two things:

- How to manage a background thread with
  an endless loop for the life time of
  an application. Application_start and
  Application_end are used.
- How to keep
  such a website (and the background
  thread) alive by restarting the site in Application_end

Comment: Thx, exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

the global asax have some event where you can manage you code...

if you destroy your objects in the apropieate event...

for Application_Start on  Application_End
for Session_Start on Session_End

if you thread is one applications variable, will be alive while the application pool is alive...

regards

Comment: So, the main thread would simply kill the background thread when the application pool would stop?

Comment: if you are using .net component yes, but, if you are using COM+ may stay on memory...

Answer (score 0):

The "auto start" feature of ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.5 is now the preferred way to start the application upon deployment and keep it running.  No more need for the "keep alive" tricks mentioned in Rick Strahl's blog (from the accepted answer).

See this [link to Scott Guthrie's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) blog entry on this feature.  Another concise post is [Mohamed Malek's technet blog entry](http://blogs.technet.com/b/meamcs/archive/2011/05/12/writing-an-iis-7-5-auto-start-provider.aspx).

Instead of starting your thread in Application_Start you create a custom class that implements IProcessHostPreloadClient.